# Question about the usefulness of "happy" and "unhappy" at SE

Tags: discussion, request

This question arises from a suggestion by FumbleFingers that I post it here for comment.

Briefly, some of the questions asked at EL&U SE are overly simple and could be handled by a routine Google search. Others are, while seemingly simple, deceptively complex - like this one about "[irony vs sarcasm.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26621/irony-vs-sarcasm/26624#26624)"

And, in answering some of the more difficult queries, elements of the language of linguistics and linguistic philosophy may be useful, as these fields of study are explicitly designed to explore such questions.

Recently, I used the terms "happy" and "unhappy" to describe the state of various utterances and was not clearly understood. I am of a mind to forward these terms to the community for consideration because I'd like to popularize their use; however, if the consensus is that they are not useful, then I'll withdraw my efforts at advocating for them.

To say that a construction is "happy" means that it is well-formed and appropriate for the purpose to which it is employed.

If a construction is "unhappy," it is failing in some aspect such that it does not succeed. There are types and classes of unhappiness, namely:

1. Misfires: Externally Unhappy Utterances.

   - a. Misinvocations: appropriate act
     fails conventional criteria.
   - b. Non-Plays: no appropriate convention.
   - c. Misapplications: convention misapplied.
   - d. Misexecutions: appropriate act rendered defective.
   - e. Flaws: conventional procedure partly rejected.
   - f. Hitches: conventional procedure not completed.
2. Abuses: Internally Unhappy Utterances.

   - a. Insincerities: appropriate intention(s) absent.
   - b. Non-Fulfillments: intention(s) not fully carried out.

This extended taxonomy is well beyond what most users would want or need to know, but I'm adding it here for the expert reader to more fully describe the ways in which a statement might be "unhappy." In my view, to say that an utterance is "wrong" or "incorrect" can be at times overly blunt.

Rather, to say that an expression is "unhappy" is a more nuanced description that something is wrong with it, either in construction or idiom, or that it fails to execute a performative utterance.

This terminology was initially popularized by JL Austin, in [*How to Do Things With Words*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._L._Austin), and further developed by John Searle in *Speech Acts* and other works. Here's a nice paper by Kevin Halion that devotes a chapter to "[Speech Acts and Their Happiness.](http://www.e-anglais.com/thesis.html#chap2)"

To sum up, this kind of terminology allows for much greater precision in the discussion of language and it is usually self-explanatory through context. I am not suggesting that we use the language of linguistics wholesale, but merely that *happiness* and *unhappiness* are exceptionally powerful terms worth community consideration.

Comment: Rather than post another Answer for the sake of it, I'll just say I'm all for this - if we can find a way to make it work without being confusing to the non-cognoscenti.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: It already has this incognoscente, i.e. me, confused!

Comment: @Cerberus: Well I guess if even *you* find this use of happy/unhappy confusing it's probably dead in the water. I quite like the terms *when I'm expecting them*, because of the way they seem to shift 'linguistic correctness' away from external judgement by (sometimes) pedants. If some word *sits well* in a given context, I'm happy for the word itself to be 'happy'. But for most people here (esp. non-native speakers) I think it would just be a confusing distraction. EL&U has enough trouble already when trying to agree on the dividing line between acceptable/unacceptable utterances.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: My problem is mostly that I do not find these terms at all obvious: without further explanation, or perhaps examples, I do not understand these distinctions at all, valuable though they may be. If the meanings of these terms should be easy to understand and remember, and useful, I could be persuaded to make an effort to learn them, though. But this list, as it stands, doesn't work for me yet. Again, I do encourage and appreciate Raven's approach, differentiating judgements of style both internally and from "grammaticality".

Comment: @Cerberus: I think we agree re the issue in hand then. Potentially useful terminology, but because it's 'opaque' to many, we shouldn't use it without in-line clarification. We're mostly quite capable of saying what we mean without specialised vocabulary, and we don't want EL&U to become a 'closed [talking-]shop'.

Comment: @FumbleFingers As the Italians would say: _se non è vero, è ben trovato_, that is aproximately, "If it's not true, at least it sounds good!"

Answer (score 13):

Interestingly, the terms I have usually heard used for this purpose are *felicitous* and *infelicitous*, marking a slightly different boundary than *grammatical* and *ungrammatical*. Whereas something might be *grammatical* in that it doesn’t violate any constitutive correctness conditions of the grammar it could be described as *infelicitous* if an average speaker might object it for one reason or another.

For example, whereas *All her friends and relatives had supported Ann throughout the ordeal* is a grammatical sentence, *Her husband had supported Ann throughout the ordeal*, while constructed the same way, might be described as *infelicitous*.

Of course, the word *felicitous* derives from Latin *felix*, meaning “happy”.

Comment: Right. "Felicitous" often arises in the literature beside these terms. It's very common to see something like, "Here, X is happy, or felicitous," etc.

Comment: This link says there's a subtle difference between linguistic *happy* and *felicitous*, but it doesn't expand on the details. More research needed, I feel... http://www.e-anglais.com/thesis.html#chap2

Comment: +1 Between *unhappy* and *infelicitous*, I prefer *infelicitous*, because it is a commonly used term that would be intelligible to most people. This does not apply to *unhappy*, which seems to be a bit too specialized or obscure in this sense. Moreover, I consider this usage of *unhappy* somewhat infelicitous, i.e. I find it a bit ugly.

Comment: Another term used for this kind of discussion is "unfortunate."

Comment: +1 for excellent example of an *infelicitous* utterance. I know I don't like the second sentence, but I can't for the life of me say exactly why. Reading it straight after the first, I got suckered into thinking it was ok. Then I thought "*Hang on...*" In programming nowadays they often say potentially dodgy code *smells*. The difference is, they can usually say why.

Comment: Strangely, I don't get any weird vibes from the second sentence. Rather, the first sounds more awkward to me.

Answer (score 9):

How is a vague wishy-washy term like *unhappy*, which doesn't sound like it has anything to do with language or grammar, supposed to allow "*greater* precision in the discussion of language"? I think systematizing something like this would be a bad idea. Call a spade a spade: if it's incorrect, say so. If it's not grammatical, say so.

Comment: But @The Raven is quite correct to say this is a term used by linguists. I think first met it in Steven Pinker (the techie book on irregular verbs, not his 'pop linguistics' blockbusters). He's not keen on prescriptivists anyway, and partly for that reason I assume that *unhappy* doesn't necessarily mean *incorrect*. It means *arguably incorrect*, or *incorrect according to some people*. I think @The Raven's proposal is a great idea if we can find a way to make it work. Much better than arguing about the difference between *incorrect* and *non-standard, but maybe tolerable*.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, here are some of the euphemisms I use:

- not stylistically pleasing
- advised against by style books
- somehow less attractive
- not generally preferred
- frowned upon by some pedants
- anacoluthon

These usually do not antagonize askers, or so I believe. Sir Humphrey might add *complicated*, *courageous*, or just *novel*.

Comment: As with @The Raven, I still don't accept that *unhappy* is a euphemism. But that's splitting hairs. I'm now convinced your alternatives (with the exception of *anacoluthon* unless it's defined at point of use) are better than introducing unfamiliar usages.

Answer (score 1):

> This extended taxonomy is well beyond what most users would want or need to know, but I'm adding it here for the expert reader to more fully describe the ways in which a statement might be "unhappy." In my view, to say that an utterance is "wrong" or "incorrect" can be at times overly blunt.

So... "unhappy" is a euphemism? I guess I don't understand why we should use euphemisms when describing an issue with a sentence when that is the entire reason they are asking us. Having a secret set of terms that means something only to us is *bad*.

I am not much of a true linguist, so if these are well accepted and used terms in the field, okay. Thanks for the head's up. I am still a little hesitant in using them, however.

Comment: I think *euphemism* is OP's own word. My understanding is the linguistic usage expands the category of 'imperfect' utterances to include things that aren't totally incorrect, but aren't exactly well-formed either. The big problem, as you say, is that it's effectively 'jargon'. With the added downside that these words are well-known with their more common meanings. But I still like them.

Comment: So... it isn't a euphemism?

Comment: Umm - not in my opinion, and certainly not the way I'd *like* to use it. And on checking I see OP didn't actually use that word. I'd like to think when he said *blunt* he meant *blunt instrument*. For me, an *unhappy* utterance needn't be 'clinically depressed' - it's just not in an ideal state.

Comment: No, these are not euphemisms at all. This terminology was applied out of necessity. The standard "right" and "wrong" are too binary to encapture the reality of language as we attempt to describe it, in the kind of detail at which technicians operate. After all, when you say you are "happy" or "unhappy," you allow for shades or degrees of meaning within those parameters. As given in the question as posted, you can see that "wrong" statements can be wrong in a number of ways. This terminology allows us to shade our judgements with greater precision.

Comment: @The Raven: Ah, I see. Thank you.